# Temporary file deletion on program termination

Tags: java

If I create a temporary file for some write operations, is there any way to specify in program  to delete it automatically on program termination.

Below is the procedure used to create file.

```
File tmp = File.createTempFile("foo", "tmp");
 System.out.println("Your temp file is " + tmp.getCanonicalPath());
 //doing something with the temporary file
writeDataInTemp(tmp.getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: Are you using any framework or a container to run your code? Usually frameworks and containers provide some sort of shutdown hook using which you can ask the container what to do before the program is terminated. In plain Java, you would have to write the deletion code in `@PreDestroy` method

Comment: No frameworks used.Deletion code you meant is some existing function?

Comment: In Predestroy examples I can see several methods:http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.annotation.PreDestroy&ei=ZxjNmOrN&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=884&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1457150499&sig=ALL1Aj7uy_LtEkUDTRqGX1wXWZ-mXKvzLw

Comment: you will have to write the code to delete a file.

Comment: Okay.Got one function to do that tmp.deleteOnExit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shutdown hook and do it yourself:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)

(That's probably how libraries and frameworks do it. It lets you define a function that is run when the JVM terminates)

You'd want to build up a list of all the temporary files somewhere (I suggest you have some nice getTemporaryFile() function that gets you the file handle and adds the name to the list of things to kill), and then kill them in your shutdown hook.

Comment: Thanks. Got one function to do that, tmp.deleteOnExit();. Any way your suggestion is a nice approach.